# Applescript: return list of subdirectories with full path

Tags: applescript

I have an Excel workbook with VBA code that needs to return a list of all sub-directories within a specified directory. It works fine using either Dir (or the FileSystemObject) on my Windows PC.

Unfortunately, the person I am writing the code for is using a Mac and neither solution has worked (obviously FileSystemObject would be unavailable on Mac OS, and the Dir command is returning only a "." or system files instead of directories).

I would like to try another approach using the VBA function MacScript, which is able to run Applescript. I have no idea how to code in Applescript and am asking for help writing a script that will take a directory (e.g. "/Test Dir") and return a list of all the sub-directories with their full paths (e.g. "/Test Dir/Sub1, /Test Dir/Sub2").

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you run a shell script rather than an Applescript, if so try this in Terminal `find /Users/fred -type d` to see if you like the format, where `fred` is some random username.

Comment: Out of interest, when you say "a list of all sub-directories", were you wanting just the folders contained within the parent folder (i.e. one level deep), or all folders within all folders of the parent folder, down to the bottom (i.e. a full-depth tree traversal) ?

Answer (score 1):

A very efficient way is to use the `find` command of the shell. It's much faster than any *native* AppelScript way like *tell*ing the `Finder` to do the job

```
set folderList to paragraphs of (do shell script "/usr/bin/find '/Test Dir' -type d")
```

The single quotes around the path are required if the path contains space characters.

Comment: Will this run from VBA using MacScript function?

Comment: I don't know. You wrote *which is able to run Applescript*